# How to set the label of subplots to be the entry of some column?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have got the unemployment data from OECD that has a monthly value for about 20 countries. It has columns 'LOCATION', 'TIME', 'Value'. I have selected the data for 4 out of these 20 countries and I would like to plot them in one figure. How could I make the label of each graph to be the country name? The labels given by the following code are all 'Value'.

I have tried to add `plt.legend(df.LOCATION.unique())` at the end, but I don't think the colours match the country name.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df.groupby('LOCATION').plot(x='TIME', y='Value', ax=ax, legend=True)
plt.show();
```

I think I can do this by adding a graph for each country one by one and set the label manually, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are seeking (please show some sample data for clarification), but maybe:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df.groupby("LOCATION").apply(
    lambda dfl: ax.plot(dfl["TIME"], dfl["Value"], label=dfl["LOCATION"].unique()[0])
)


ax.legend()
```